# How to see exit status of an exe in java

Tags: java, windows

I am using this code to run an exe file. And according to how this exe is cancelled or finished, it returns exit status of -1, 1 accordingly. I want to get this exit status in my code. This is the code I use to open the file, any other code that will help me solve this problem is also appreciated.

```
try {
    Process p;
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(updateFolder.getPath() +"\\myapp.exe");
    System.out.println(p);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue()

Comment: No OS where JavaSE runs, including Windows, supports negative values for process exit status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First wait for the process to exit, then get the exit value:

```
try {
    Process p;
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(updateFolder.getPath() +"\\myapp.exe");

    // Wait for the process to exit
    p.waitFor();

    // Get the exit value
    int result = p.exitValue();

    System.out.println(result);
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

See the [API documentation of class `java.lang.Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html).

Comment: `waitFor()` also returns the exit status, but if the program tries to write more to stdout (or stderr, less likely) than fits in the pipe buffer this deadlocks.